# Can I install an ad hoc build on iPad for an iPhone targeted app?

Tags: iphone, ipad, adhoc

I'm creating an app targeted at iPhone/iTouch devices. They build on that just fine. Can I install an ad hoc build onto an iPad while having the 'Targeted Device Family' set to iPhone and not iPhone/iPad? I'm expecting of course because it isn't a universal app that it will run in the small window on the iPad. I don't have an iPad, client does and would just like to test on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure; you just need to set "iOS Deployment Target" (IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET) correctly (i.e. 3.2 if your client has not updated to 4.2 yet).

Note that Apple has rejected iPhone-only apps with IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=3.2 (and SDKROOT=iphoneos4.0). The only thing you could do was set iOS Deployment Target to 3.1.3 and below (and be forced to support iPhone/3.1.3), which was a bit of a pain since 3.2 has a lot of improvements on 3.1.

I'm not sure if they've fixed it. You have three options:

- IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=3.1.3 (or below) and support old phones as well. (Don't support OS versions you can't test on!)
- IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=3.2 and face possible rejection.
- IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=4.0 (or above) and force users to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as the target OS matches the version of the iPad it should work.